# 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

столкнулся с такой проблемой, что когда я запускаю телеграм бота, выдаёт ошибку связанную с отсутствием атрибута в модуле. Это очень странно, т.к. при импорте данной библиотеки, данный атрибут всегда импортируется, я не понимаю в чём здесь ошибка

```
import telebot

token = "<TOKEN>"

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])

def first (message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hello")
bot.polling()
```

Comment: Скорее всего, вы установили не ту библиотеку. Попробуйте так: `pip uninstall telebot` и `pip install PyTelegramBotAPI`

Comment: А как потом эти модули правильно установить?

Comment: Вам нужен модули PyTelegramBotAPI и telebot разом? В вопросе у вас код по PyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но у меня возникает вопрос, почему telebot не работает, ведь я его импортирую?

Comment: Это разные библиотеки и у них одинаковый файл импорта

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Держи

```
pip3 install PyTelegramBotAPI
```

Comment: Oh, thank you sir :)

Comment: Если ответ помог, то поставь галочку возле ответа